# How do I pass over two values to a function and print out the return value of this function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I´m currently working on an simple project, but ran into some problems.

I´ve got problems with the "fundamentalShareValue(epsTelefonica, bpsTelefonica)" function, my goal is to hand over the two parameters "epsTelefonica" and "bpsTelefonica" because I need them to do the math in the "fundamentalShareValue()" function.

And then at the end of the function I return the value "fSVTelefonica", which I want to print later on, which also doesn´t quite work...

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
def parseBPST():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TEF.MC/key-statistics?p=TEF.MC"
    )
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    bpsTelefonica = soup.find_all(
        "td", {"class": "Fw(500) Ta(end) Pstart(10px) Miw(60px)"}
    )[56].text
    return bpsTelefonica


def parseEPST():
    r = requests.get("https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TEF.MC?p=TEF.MC")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    epsTelefonica = (
        soup.find_all("td", {"class": "Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"})[11].find("span").text
    )
    return epsTelefonica


def fundamentalShareValue(epsTelefonica, bpsTelefonica):
    fSVTelefonica = math.sqrt(22.5 * epsTelefonica * bpsTelefonica)
    print(fSVTelefonica)
    return fSVTelefonica
```

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. You explained what you want - just do it. If you do not know how to call a function with parameters, SO is not the right place to learn about that.

Comment: "which also doesn´t quite work..." is not exactly stating what your current and desired output is. Also, just the functions without any calls achieve nothing, so you might want to add the full code.

Comment: @DocDriven Later on I want to print out the return value of the fundamentalShareValue function:

print("Telefonica fSV: " + str(fundamentalShareValue()))

And that doesn´t work.

Comment: You can find guidelines on how to ask question on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. To be able to help, you have to edit your question so that it contains the full code (so that we are able to reproduce your results), your current output (error messages, etc.), your desired output (in your case a kind of string, it seems) and what you have tried so far. Adding code in the comments is hard to read and might delay a response that helps you. At the moment, I have no clue what you are trying to achieve and hence, I cannot even attempt to help you.

Answer (score 0):

check the values returned by the first two functions.

```
bpsTelefonica = parseBPST()
print(bpsTelefonica)
epsTelefonica = parseEPST()
print(epsTelefonica)
fundamentalShareValue(epsTelefonica, bpsTelefonica)
```